# Mysql queries mindnumbingly slow

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

I am having issues with an InnoDB mysql database. E.g., I have two tables, events and events_artists with the following architecture:

```
events:
id (PK)
host_id
date

events_artists:
id (PK)
event_id
artist_id
```

The table events has about 100,000 entries, events_artists holds about 150,000.

One of the things I have to do is check for entries in the table events that are not referred to in the table events_artists. To do that, in another post I have received the query

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE id IS NULL OR id NOT IN (SELECT event_id FROM events_artists)
```

From the logic, this query looks good to me. However, it is just *extremely* slow. I let it run for one hour now, and still no result. Something has to be wrong there.

I am grateful for any help on how to optimize this!

Thanks

Charles

**SOLUTION FOUND**

The following query makes the statement much faster:

```
SELECT * 
FROM events a
     LEFT JOIN events_artists b
     ON a.id = b.event_id
     WHERE b.event_id IS NULL;
```

However, the main speed boost was adding ***foreign keys***. I had to remove them in the interim for some duplicate search and added them back now, which increases speed a lot. While the query took more than an hour before, it only takes ***one second*** now.

Thank you!

Charles

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN <your select query here>` say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get faster results you should avoid using sub-query. Alternatively you can try using LEFT JOIN to get records which are in events but not in events_artists.

Visit [Visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

```
SELECT * 
FROM events a
     LEFT JOIN events_artists b
         ON a.id = b.event_id
WHERE b.event_id IS NULL;
```

Also make sure that you have index on columns id and event_id for faster query execution.

Comment: Thank you, Omesh! I have updated the question with your solution and another edit. Also thanks for the great link!

Answer (score 1):

If you run an `EXPLAIN` of your query, you'll see the subquery is treated as `DEPENDENT`, which means it'll be run once for each row in your `events` table, hence it's slow.

You can change it to be independent like so:

```
SELECT events.*
FROM events
LEFT JOIN events_artists ON (events.id = events_artists.event_id)
WHERE events_artists.event_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select 
    ev.* from events as ev 
    left join events_artists as ea on ev.id=ea.event_id
where 
    ea.event_id is null or ev.id is null
```